# How to declare a global variable that other web forms can also use in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, global-variables, webforms

Here is a sample global declaration variable:

```
Public Shared str as String
```

But this global declaration is only for one web form. Is it possible to declare a global variable that other web forms can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web programming, ie: asp.net, is stateless.  Meaning that unlike traditional desktop programming one page request has nothing to do with another.

There are a few standard ways of sharing information amongst pages: Global, Session, Cookies, Cache, Database, Query String parameters and Form Post parameters.

**Global** - data is stored in a global variable declared in your global.asax file.  This data is available across all users/pages and will survive until IIS does a reset or you purposefully clear it out.  Generally a very very bad idea as you can easily run into threading issues when the values are changing and you usually aren't sharing a changeable value across all users/sessions.

**Session** - data is stored server side (or in memory of the web server or in a state server).  This is per user.  Good for single web server implementations; however has some drawbacks that are too complicated for this simple post regarding load balanced web servers.  In memory sessions are subject to being cleared during app restarts; state servers will allow session values to be persisted in that event.   However, state servers generally require a database round trip which usually negates all advantages in using it over making regular database calls.

**Cookies** - data is stored in the browser and sent on every page request.  This is per user.  Good for small amounts of data, generally less than 4KB.  However, the data is sent to the browser and is certainly able to be inspected by the end user.  Usually you'll want the data encrypted.  No issues for load balanced web servers; however will result in a slightly larger amount of data being sent back and forth between the client and server.  Also no issues with regards to web server restarts.  Can be set to automatically clear once the browser is closed.

**Cache** - Data is stored in a caching mechanism like memcache that may or may not be on the same machine as the web server.  Typically for more advanced distributed applications.  Do your research.

**Database** - Data is stored in some type of database such as MS SQL Server.  Great for persisted data that needs to survive long term.  Drawbacks are that it requires a DB call to pull data on demand; this is mitigated by general hardware and network speeds.  Note that session state servers have the exact same drawback.

**Query String** - Easy way to transfer some data between pages.  Such as showing a list of accounts on one page and linking to a single account view on another.  Not generally useful for keeping a piece of data throughout an application.  Makes it easy to book mark specific views on a site.

**Form Post** - Similar to query string.  Primary difference is that the data is posted from one page to another as opposed to being on the query string line; also this one is not book markable.

Comment: ahh so there are other ways, thanks for this sir, the explanations are very clear.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: I would say if you are just starting out to use either sessions or cookies.  They are by far the easiest to figure out the basics of.

Comment: Ok sir i will study both of them first before using, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by using the type name of the webform, something like this

```
Dim thisstr = MainPage.str
lblSomeLabel.Text = thisstr
```

However, you should note that every time a page is loaded, the entire ASP.Net stack is rebuilt.  (It's a bit more complicated than that, but it's enough for now).  Because of that, variables will not persist between page requests.

You might want to look into using a Session variable.

Comment: Ahh yes sir you have a point, I will try study and use session variable, thanks for the advice sir, very helpful :)